# Can I use Electrons built in IPC to communicate with .NET app?

Tags: .net, electron, node-ipc

I'm looking into building an Electron application which needs to be able to send messages to a separate .NET application on the same machine.

Is it possible to use the built-in IPC-library `(ipcRenderer/ipcMain)` to communicate outside of Electron, not just between renderer and main? Or do I need to use a separate ipc-library like [node-ipc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ipc) for this?

I have tried to use HTTP-communication in other projects, but that doesn't feel right for this application.

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot, electron's ipc is for electron's own processes only.